(OSError: (Errno 22) Invalid argument)-Plotly dash graph object failes to render if large dataset with the OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
A callback method fails to render the graph when the dataset choosen is larger. I am unable to understand the error.Also how do we handle such callback exceptions in Python. The error is this.
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 363, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "//lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 327, in execute
    write(data)
  File "//site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 302, in write
    self.wfile.write(data)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 826, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument


Application run code
port=8050
app.run(debug=True, jupyter_mode="external", dev_tools_hot_reload=False, port=port, host="0.0.0.0")

Tried this didn't help
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL  
signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_DFL)

